# Floating a fixed-size div to the right and having a flexible width div on the left

Tags: html, css, width

I got the outcome I wanted (http://jsfiddle.net/jcx3X/40/), but I'm just curious as to why this (http://jsfiddle.net/jcx3X/41/) doesn't work. Why must the `div` listed first in the HTML be the one to be floated?

Comment: Well, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the html is what determines the order of the *dom* (document object model) elements. The element that is not floated will act differently depending on the order.

Maybe [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/jcx3X/44/) will help you on your quest. I just happened to be doing something similar.

HTML

```
<header class="global-header">
  header
</header>

<div class="container">

  <div class="column sidebar">

    aside content fixed width

  </div>

  <div class="column page">
    main content flexible width
  </div>

</div> <!-- .container -->
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.global-header {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.page {
  float: none; /* just to be clear */
  background: #C0FFEE;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  float: right;
  background-color: #f06;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
```